# Prometheus add extra label on join request without using group statement?

Tags: prometheus

I am working with Prometheus.
I have the following metrics:

Metric1

```
{"metric":{"namespace":"ns1", "instance_id":"someid", "label2":"somevalue", "label4":somethingelse"},"values":[[1675145655,"1"]]}
```

Metric2

```
{"metric":{"namespace":"ns1", "instance_id":"someid", "label3":"someothervalue"},"values":[[1675145655,"1"]]}
```

So both metrics have namespace and instance_id label, and then they have additional labels (label2, 3, 4).

I am doing a join request on them with the following request:

```
(metric1{namespace="ns1"} == 1) * on (namespace, instance_id)  (metric2{namespace="ns1", label3="something"} == 1)
```

Now, this is 1:1 join, for a specific time, I should never have two metrics with the same instance_id, so no need to perform many_to_1 or many_to_many here.

However, I wish to include in the result label present in metric1, but not metric2.
If I do the following:

```
(metric1{namespace="ns1"} == 1) * on (namespace, instance_id) group_left() (metric2{namespace="ns1", label3="something"} == 1)
```

It works well, my result will contain the extra label from metric1:

```
{"metric":{"label2":"somevalue", "label4":"somethingelse"},"values":[[1675145655,"1"]]}
```

What I am trying to confirm is:

- From my understanding, group_left/right command is made for many:many. I guess that since 1:1 is included in many:many, group_left/right also works for 1:1. But, can I add extra label in a simple 1:1 request? Or do I have to use the many:many join if I want to do so?

-On top of that, when I read [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#group-modifiers), it states that

```
Label lists can be provided to the group modifier which contain labels from the "one"-side to be included in the result metrics.
```

But here this the reverse I have, the label I get in my results are the one I did not put in the group_left. So for example if I do this request instead:

```
(metric1{namespace="ns1"} == 1) * on (namespace, instance_id) group_left(label2) (metric2{namespace="ns1", label3="something"} == 1)
```

Then the result give me metrics like this:

```
{"metric":{"label4":"somethingelse"},"values":[[1675145655,"1"]]}
```

I have all extra label BUT the one I put my group_left statement. Is that expected? Am I mis reading the documentation here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use `group_left()` for `1:1` query if you need retaining all the labels from time series on the **left** side (or from the **right** side if `group_right()` is used). This doesn't introduce performance penalty.

If you put a list of labels inside `group_left()`, then these labels will be copied from time series on the **right** side additionally to all the labels from time series on the **left** side of the [specified binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#binary-operators).

See more details in [the official docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#group-modifiers).

If you need retaining only some labels from the left side, then just drop unneeded labels after the calculations of `q1 * on (...) group_left() q2`. Prometheus doesn't provide functions, which can drop unneeded labels from time series (or leave only the needed labels), but this functionality can be emulated with `sum(...) without (...)` or `sum(...) by (...)` in most cases. For example, the following query leaves only `(namespace, instance_id, label2)` labels from time series matching `metric1{namespace="ns1"}` in the result:

```
sum(
  (metric1{namespace="ns1"} == 1)
    * on (namespace, instance_id) group_left()
  (metric2{namespace="ns1", label3="something"} == 1)
) by (namespace, instance_id, label2)
```

Note that the [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) may return unexpected results if multiple time series have the same set of output labels specified inside `by (...)`.

P.S. Take a look also at [label_del](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_del) and [label_keep](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_keep) functions provided by VictoriaMetrics - the Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. These functions are easier to use instead of `sum(...) by (...)` or `sum(...) without (...)` trick when some labels need to be dropped / left in the result.